# MySQL assumes partial `pwrite()` means disk is full

Tags: mysql, c, linux, posix

I'm supporting a large customer, running a few MySQL 5.5.59 databases on Centos 6 or 7 virtual servers running under VMWare.  MySQL databases are stored on XFS filesystems on iSCSI LUNs.

I'm getting intermittent corrupt tables correlated with errors such as this in the MySQL error logs:

```
180619 15:08:38  InnoDB: Error: Write to file (merge) failed at offset 0 656408576
InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 921600 were written.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 0.
InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
InnoDB: Error number 0 means 'Success'.
```

The disk(s) are never full, there are no quotas, and the file size is a few GB (2-6) and well within the range of supported file sizes on XFS on 64-bit Linux.

**And note that `errno` is `0`.**

The MySQL code that generates this error is `storage/innobase/os/os0file.c`.  It blindly assumes **ANY** partial write must mean the disk is full (full MySQL source for 5.5 is available at https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html):

```
ret = os_file_pwrite(file, buf, n, offset, offset_high);

if ((ulint)ret == n) {

    return(TRUE);
}

if (!os_has_said_disk_full) {

    ut_print_timestamp(stderr);

    fprintf(stderr,
        "  InnoDB: Error: Write to file %s failed"
        " at offset %lu %lu.\n"
        "InnoDB: %lu bytes should have been written,"
        " only %ld were written.\n"
        "InnoDB: Operating system error number %lu.\n"
        "InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system"
        " support files of this size.\n"
        "InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full"
        " or a disk quota exceeded.\n",
        name, offset_high, offset, n, (long int)ret,
        (ulint)errno);
    if (strerror(errno) != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,
            "InnoDB: Error number %lu means '%s'.\n",
            (ulint)errno, strerror(errno));
    }

    fprintf(stderr,
        "InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers"
        " are described at\n"
        "InnoDB: "
        REFMAN "operating-system-error-codes.html\n");

    os_has_said_disk_full = TRUE;
}

return(FALSE);
```

The relevant part of MySQL's InnoDB `os_file_pwrite()` function (it's a wrapper around the actual `pwrite()` function call):

```
/*******************************************************************//**
Does a synchronous write operation in Posix.
@return number of bytes written, -1 if error */
static
ssize_t
os_file_pwrite(
/*===========*/
    os_file_t   file,   /*!< in: handle to a file */
    const void* buf,    /*!< in: buffer from where to write */
    ulint       n,  /*!< in: number of bytes to write */
    ulint       offset, /*!< in: least significant 32 bits of file
                offset where to write */
    ulint       offset_high) /*!< in: most significant 32 bits of
                offset */
{
    ssize_t ret;
    off_t   offs;

    ut_a((offset & 0xFFFFFFFFUL) == offset);

    /* If off_t is > 4 bytes in size, then we assume we can pass a
    64-bit address */

    if (sizeof(off_t) > 4) {
        offs = (off_t)offset + (((off_t)offset_high) << 32);
    } else {
        offs = (off_t)offset;

        if (offset_high > 0) {
            fprintf(stderr,
                "InnoDB: Error: file write"
                " at offset > 4 GB\n");
        }
    }

    os_n_file_writes++;

#if defined(HAVE_PWRITE) && !defined(HAVE_BROKEN_PREAD)
    os_mutex_enter(os_file_count_mutex);
    os_file_n_pending_pwrites++;
    os_n_pending_writes++;
    os_mutex_exit(os_file_count_mutex);

    ret = pwrite(file, buf, (ssize_t)n, offs);

    os_mutex_enter(os_file_count_mutex);
    os_file_n_pending_pwrites--;
    os_n_pending_writes--;
    os_mutex_exit(os_file_count_mutex);

# ifdef UNIV_DO_FLUSH
    if (srv_unix_file_flush_method != SRV_UNIX_LITTLESYNC
        && srv_unix_file_flush_method != SRV_UNIX_NOSYNC
        && !os_do_not_call_flush_at_each_write) {

        /* Always do fsync to reduce the probability that when
        the OS crashes, a database page is only partially
        physically written to disk. */

        ut_a(TRUE == os_file_flush(file));
    }
# endif /* UNIV_DO_FLUSH */

    return(ret);
```

A cursory examination of the rest of the MySQL source seems to indicate that MySQL pretty much gives up after getting a partial `pwrite()`, resulting in data corruption in the database.

The [POSIX standard for `pwrite()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) states that a partial write is an acceptable result and implies that it is not an error condition:

> The `write()` function shall attempt to write `nbyte` bytes from the
>   buffer pointed to by `buf` to the file associated with the open file
>   descriptor, `fildes`.
>
> ...
>
> The `pwrite()` function shall be equivalent to `write()` ...
>
> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of
>   bytes actually written to the file associated with `fildes`. This
>   number shall never be greater than `nbyte`. Otherwise, `-1` shall be
>   returned and `errno` set to indicate the error.

Per POSIX, the only `errno` value that indicates a full disk is:

> [ENOSPC]
>       There was no free space remaining on the device containing the file.

This to me is a MySQL bug - a partial `pwrite()` result is not an error condition and does not necessarily mean that the underlying disk is full - **especially when `errno` is `0`**.

I'm specifically asking if my interpretation of POSIX is correct.  If so, I plan on filing a MySQL bug report as I expect a database to be reliable.

Comment: Note that regardless of posix, it has been an underlying assumption across all unixes that write()(and similar functions such as pwrite)  on a **regular file** (*as opposed to other devices such as pipes or sockets*) will always write the entire buffer - and if that does not happen, some hard error has occured. I do not know whether this is stated in any official documentation though. - it is probably still worth it to file a bug report.

Comment: `errno` is 0 because if `write` returns a short count, no error is raised until the *next* attempt to write. From your link: "If a write() requests that more bytes be written than there is room for ... only as many bytes as there is room for shall be written. For example, suppose there is space for 20 bytes more in a file before reaching a limit. A write of 512 bytes will return 20. **The next write of a non-zero number of bytes would give a failure return** ... " Yes, there is a bug in MySQL because it bails before it has determined the reason for the short count.

Comment: @nos *it has been an underlying assumption across all unixes that write()(and similar functions such as pwrite) on a regular file (as opposed to other devices such as pipes or sockets) will always write the entire buffer*  I know - I have **never** seen a short write before.  Yet I got about 6 of them yesterday.  I'm thinking it has to be something specific about my customer's "cloud" configuration. I'm wondering how much other software out there is going to have problems on such clouds as layers upon layers of virtualization do things that undermine previous assumptions about reliability.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Hence my recommendation of filing a bug report - with as much technical information about the environment(filesystem, iSCSI configuration, VMWare version, kernel version and so on) as possible.

Comment: WRT "underlying assumption" about short write. I'm glad I do not know about such assumption. The documentation explicitly says it's not the case. First, `man pwrite` says "Note that is not an error for a successful call to transfer fewer bytes than requested (see read(2) and write(2))." And then `man write` repeats that and even gives an example: "If a write() is interrupted by a signal handler before any bytes are written, then the call fails with the error EINTR; if it is interrupted after at least one byte has been written, the call succeeds, and  returns  the number of bytes written."

Comment: In other words, I do think it's a MySQL bug and a bug report should be filed

Comment: @dvk Thanks for the reference to a signal interrupting the write.  I'm wondering if that might be happening - writing a full MB over an iSCSI LUN in the customer's environment likely takes a long time and the underlying data transfer consists of a pretty substantial number of individual SCSI requests and network packets.  I'm also wondering if I'm hitting some SCSI timeout in that long sequence.